# Is there a way to open multiple instances of CMD's with Azure-Pipelines?

Tags: windows, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cd

I'm using Azure-Pipelines for my CI. In my pipeline, I need to use multiple instances of a CMD (Windows). For example, one CMD needs to start and continuously run a server, while the other needs to then deploy an app while the server is still running.

When using the CMD task, it only uses one instance of the CMD, so when I run the server, it never finishes and never gets to running the app.

Is there a way to run multiple instances of a CMD with Azure-Pipelines?

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to try out below solution, Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can start cmd.exe on the agent machine from a powershell task using [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7) command.

So you can add multiple powershell tasks to start multiple CMD instances on the agent machine. Or you can start multiple CMD instances in one powershell task. Se below example:

```
steps:
  - powershell: |
    'Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -verb runas -ArgumentList {/k echo "hello"}' 
  - powershell: |
    'Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -verb runas -ArgumentList {/k echo "world"}'
```